# Can overflow text be centered?

Tags: css, text, overflow, center, alignment

When I specify `text-align:center` for an element with a width that is greater than the width of the text, the text is centered within the content box of the element (as expected).

When I specify `text-align:center` for an element with a width that is less than the width of the text, the text is aligned to the left edge of the content box and overflows the right edge of the content box.

You can see the two cases in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ansciath/5EZKE/).

Can any CSS magic make the text equally overflow both the left edge and the right edge of the content box, so that it stays centered?

Comment: Do you need the `white-space: nowrap;`? If not, the text appears centered.

Comment: @feeela: I used `white-space:nowrap` in order to keep the text on a single line, which is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I know this question is old, but I just had the same Problem and found a much easier solution with just a span.
http://jsfiddle.net/7hy3w2jj/

```
<div>some text</div>
<div>
    <span class="text-overflow-center">some text that will overflow</span>
</div>
```

Then you just need this definition

```
.text-overflow-center {
    margin-left: -100%;
    margin-right: -100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you can work with pseudo elements, it can be done with no html at all.
Just add these definition to your text container. http://jsfiddle.net/7287L9a8/

```
div:before {
    content: "";
    margin-left: -100%;
}
div:after {
    content: "";
    margin-right: -100%;
}
```

The only downside to the pseudo variant is that it only works with one line of text.

Comment: oh thank gods for negative margins! I used `-99px` instead of % value for a child element that is much smaller than the parent which has variable dimensions and `overflow: hidden` anyway

Comment: Can't this be simplified to `margin:0 -100%;` ?

Comment: @Aziz probably. But I like to only define properties that I use.

Comment: MS Edge browser is breaking ;-(

Comment: For MSEdge, if you [can use flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) — then putting `display: flex; justify-content: center;` on the `div` works better cross-browser. http://jsfiddle.net/jfroom/2u5x1hmj/1/  @Nemo64 consider an update?

Comment: IE 11 also needed `display:flex;` on the pseudo elements. http://jsfiddle.net/jfroom/2u5x1hmj/4/

Comment: @jfroom thanks. Isn't `text-align: center` still required for ie9 and below?

Comment: @Nemo64 Yes, `text-align: center` still needed for fallback - just tested on IE9 and breaks without it. I don't have any IE8 or below images handy at the moment to test further back. That prop is also on the last v4 link.

Comment: This doesn't work at all, does it? Try making the div 15px wide instead of 100px, and things won't be centered anymore.

Comment: I have a small div which has fixed width and text therein overflow. I don't want all the text to be in one line, which is the case when I apply your solution. I want text to be multiple lines and when some line is overflowing it should overflow equally to both left and right rather than just overflowing in one direction. Here is the link to my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ew52qj7b/
I don't want to use break-word as it doesn't look good

Comment: @Gaurav i think there is no way to achieve this without having all lines overflowing equally, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ew52qj7b/1/ You could take a look at hyphenation but the browser support isn't that good for automatic hyphenation: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-hyphens but depending on the situation you can use &shy; to allow hyphens in a specific spot.

Comment: @Nemo64 Actually I'm fine with all the lines overflowing, so your solution is the best I am possibly gonna get, Thanks

Comment: Here's a one-liner to apply this answer to a centre-aligned text element `e` in JavaScript: `if(e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth) e.style.marginRight = e.style.marginLeft = "-100%";`. 

Or to set just one margin, and use non-relative values, `if(e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth) e.style.marginLeft = (e.offsetWidth - e.scrollWidth)/2 + 'px';`. 

Note that these must be called after adding the element to the DOM, so that their offsetWidth & scrollWidth can be calculated!

Comment: Very nice, thanks. People (at least one!) are still having this problem today. It should be noted that the -100% is the size of the containing box, not the size of the text, so the solution requires knowing roughly the maximum ratio between overflowed text and the box size.

Answer (score 43):

This looks some old question.

Now I think there is some good answer with flex.

You can do this simply like this:

```
<div id="small_div">overflowing text</div>

#small_div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

That's it.

Hope much help to you!

Comment: Just a heads up. This doesn't work in IE11 and older (even with the autoprefixer).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it allows multiline overflow centering

Comment: This is a good starting point but I had to also add `text-align: center;` to get multiline centering with and also overflowing

Comment: flex box doesnt center overflowing content for me i still need to add margin-left: -100%;
    margin-right: -100%;

Answer (score 14):

Div magic to the rescue. In case anyone is interested, you can see the solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ansciath/5EZKE/22/).

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="text">some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="text">some text that will overflow</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: silver;
}
#inner {
    /* shrink-to-fit width */
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    /* shift left edge of text to center */
    left: 50%;
}
#text {
    /* shift left edge of text half distance to left */
    margin-left: -50%;
    /* text should all be on one line */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: "Div magic to the rescue." Well, and DIV-soup to the rescue too… but a tricky solution

Comment: @feeela: agreed that divs can become a swirling mess, which is why I leave them out of the HTML and build the more complex DOM with JavaScript when the page is loaded.

Comment: This might be an option: http://jsfiddle.net/PdER5/. I'm purposely not posting it as answer because it needs to be heavily tested to make sure it doesn't do anything weird when it's used on your actual page in any of the browsers you need to support.

Comment: @thirtydot: breaks if the width of the text is more than twice the "random number", though in practice it could be made large enough that it wouldn't be an issue

Comment: @thirtydot IMHO a cooler solution, but the negative margins aren't "some random number", but the left positioning distance plus half the `DIV`s width.

Comment: @NathanRyan that sounds gross.

Comment: This works, and it makes a lot of sense if you think about it for a little while.  The top answer doesn't actually work.

Comment: I finally got it working. I needed to add 'text-align:left;' to #text div, in order to use it in a Wordpress website title (which already had a 'text-align:center;' assigned, I imagine...)

Answer (score 0):

Strange requirement. I would expand the boxes to the texts size.

One possible solution might involve a negative text-indent: `text-indent: -50px;`, but that won't work for smaller texts (first `DIV` in your example). No better idea here right now.

Comment: Nice thought with `text-indent`. It can replace `margin-left` in my solution with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

instead of:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

or do you only want it on one line?

Comment: this is an odd requirement. Why do you need it spill out of the element?

Comment: The element is effectively a shape, the text a label. I'm trying my hand at making certain kinds of charts with minimal JavaScript.

Comment: Why not try having the background as an image and then having the image set to no-repeat and centered. for example http://jsfiddle.net/C4BBS/1/ you can see the border shows the actual width of the div but the bg is centered

Comment: some things like the border are still messy, and some additional code would be required to handle user events on the element.

Comment: Which events are likely? the borders are not needed but i left them there so you can see that the actual width of the element.

Comment: mousing events (onclick, onmousemove, etc.) are a must. In my solution, the events can bubble to the smaller, outer container and be handled by checking whether the curser coordinates are within the container. Would be more difficult (though not impossible) to do with your solution, I think

Comment: oh okay, with mouse events such as those my solution would not work :)

Answer (score 0):

this one seems to work:
add a wrapper block with position relative and left:50% margin-left:-100% you can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LSpCS/1/)
Here's the code:

```
<style>
div {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    height:1.5em;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: silver;
}
span{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-100%;
}
</style>
<div><span>some text</span></div>
<div><span>some text that will overflow</span></div>
```

Comment: Unlucky with the text length, it makes your solution *appear* to work, until you add more text like I've done here: http://jsfiddle.net/LSpCS/2/

Comment: Nice, one less level of nested elements.

Comment: @thirtydot: bummer, was hoping. I wonder if there's a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

To make the solution work for multi-line text, you can modify Nathan's solution by changing the #inner left from 50% to 25%.

Answer (score 0):

Give the innermost `div` some `margin: 0 -50%`. If the elements are all display block or inline-block and text alignment is centered, this provides more shoulder room for the innermost element's text. At least, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is transform.

```
.parent{
        position: relative;
}

.child{
        left: 50%;
        /* transform: translate(-50%, 0); */
        translate: -50% 0;
        position: absolute;
        white-space: nowrap;
}
```

the `left` is relative to parent

the `translate` is relative to self

---

the accepted answer using `margin:0 -100%;` will overflow the text larger than 100%....